# Fritz!Box 7490 static port forwarding -> no form or options

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, fritzbox

I am trying to **setup portforwarding on a Fritzbox 7490** running FRITZ!OS 6.9 to enable a FHEM application to be reachable from the internet.

If I choose automatic port forwarding and allow all ports to be opened (there are tick boxes to allow this), everything works.

For security reasons I would like to only open the ports I need via the static port forwarding option (see https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/knowledge-base/publication/show/893_Setting-up-static-port-sharing/).

However when I click "New Sharing" -> "Port Sharing", **I have no drop-down list "Application". Actually there is no form or option displayed at all.** I only can click "OK" or "Cancel". If I click "OK" there is a info box asking me to select an application.

I would be very grateful for you help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure if it helps: When I click on "New Sharing" (in the German interface, so with different names), a window appears that contains the "Application" drop-down list together with other options. Possibly a bug in the English GUI vs. the German GUI?

Comment: I am actually also using the German interface, but thought I reach a wider audience writing in English.
The exact window you are describing is empty (but the OK and Cancel button).

Comment: @racon Try a different browser.

Comment: That was it thanks a lot! I added you comment as an answer, but if you want you can answer the question, too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem could be circumvented by changing the browser.
The problem occurred with Firefox 57.0.1. With Chrome all forms and options are shown as expected.

Very straight forward, but I didn't think of trying that in the first place.